# How do I test a command line application that does not take parameters?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, command-line, mocha.js, chai

I have a command line application that takes 4 arguments and I am now writing unit tests for them. I just have some questions about how to exactly write these tests since my function does not take in any parameters?

So in console, to run the app it would be 
test.js arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
output.

I can wrap the entire function in a bigger function and assign parameters and then test it that way, but is there a better method? Like fake input from user?

```
function test(){
  arg1 = process.argv[2];
  arg2 = process.argv[3];
  arg3 = process.argv[4];
  arg4 = process.argv[5];

  console.log(arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4);
}
```

So I want to test if any of the input is empty? the error should produce "Need all 4 entries". That's the jist of it, how do I write the unit test for that?

Comment: I would advise against doing a test like this. Instead, have tests for each individual feature without having to call the executable that verifies the features work. Then you can add tests that call that executable that just verify that the correct exit code is returned when given correct parameters.

Doing a full end to end test will be quite brittle.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with JavaScript, so the following suggestion may not work in exactly the described way.  I hope you can in this case easily "port" the idea to something similar that works in JavaScript...

What you could probably do is the following: Have some function `validateCommandLineArgs` and pass it `process.argv` as its argument:

```
function validateCommandLineArgs(argsArray){
    ... check if argsArray has four elements etc.
}
```

From your unit-tests, you can then call `validateCommandLineArgs` with arbitrarily created arrays to find if there are bugs in the way the function validates the arguments in different scenarios.